# Identify Aircraft in Petra Album Art

Tags: aircraft-identification, propeller-aircraft

[image: Petra's "Beyond Belief" album cover photo]

Was listening to one of Petra's old songs, when I noted the aircraft in the cover image. I tried searching on the net, but couldn't find anything.

It appears to be a pusher aircraft, with a four blade propeller.. that's all I could gather from the image. There are markings "ANG" (?) but I do not know how helpful that is.

This is from Petra's album titled "Beyond Belief".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a C-130 Hercules.  Of the four engines , the only feature prominently visible is the outboard left propeller.

I'm not sure why you thought it might have a "pusher" configuration-- the nose is to the left (off the edge of the photo), and vertical tail (with the "ANG" logo) is showing near the center of the photo.

Other prominent features are the flap attached to the trailing-edge of the (left) wing, and the (lit-up) back end of the fuel tank attached below the left wing between the two engines on that wing.

Comment: The reason I thought it was a pusher was that the half of the aircraft with ANG inscribed seemed to be too short to be the rear of the plane, and I was seeing things sorta out of proportion. After you pointed it out, yes, that part is actually the tail. Thanks for the fast answer! C-130 it is.

Comment: ANG is most likely a reference to "Air National Guard".

Comment: @Milwrdfan -- agreed--

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer - funny thing.  When I looked at the photo, just the same as you, that appeared to the *front* of the plane (ie on the right) for some reason!

Comment: What I really want to know, is what's with all the water all over the floor?

Comment: @quietflyer looks like the aircraft is outside and we are looking into the hangar. Picture was taken at night with the hangar lights on. Exposure makes it look brighter inside.

Comment: @quiet flyer, when it comes to night shoots & paved areas, directors of photography can't stop themselves from a  having a "wet-down" for wide shots. It helps with lighting, & the contrast & reflections look great. It's a stylistic touch that goes back to the early days of cinema. It doesn't even need to be night time, you'll often see extremely wet roads in movies, but nothing else will be wet, not cars or roofs,& nobody will be wearing wet weather gear. The paving will be shiny with puddles because it was hosed down just seconds before the cameras rolled.

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer -- funny how the viewing screen makes such a difference-- on my laptop, if I held it at the right angle I could clearly see that the left outboard engine nacelle blocked part of the external (underslung) fuel tank from view-- on my phone screen the image is too dark to discern that-- on laptop, tilting the screen to change viewing angle has an effect like changing contrast on photo-- not on phone screen--

Comment: @quietflyer Yes I have seen this kinda stuff happening before. Different colors appear relatively different on different devices.. for instance, my Samsung phone makes colors (and audio XD) more vivid. However, the screen-tilting contrast variation doesn't come on my laptop (I have noticed this on other laptops though) - I guess there's some anti-glare built in.